# css variable length columns extending too far

Tags: html, css

Not a front-end UI but have a (probably) very easy problem to fix. Here is a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/trestles/U7mYT/  I have two floated elements shown in this screen shot. One is floated left and the other (index-right-content) is floated right. The floated right div has two columns of content. The second column is much longer but doesn't expand out the box to push down the container. The index-right-content is posistion:relative. The index-right-content is the blue dashed border.

thx

[image]

**edit #1** 
fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/trestles/U7mYT/

I think the issue is the 'index-box right' which is right floated needs some way to clear itself but adding a clear:both didn't seem to do it.

don't do this full-time so thx for any help

Comment: show some css , will be helpful to track the problem.

Comment: there's so much :-( let me try to isolate it.

Comment: you can create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for that

Comment: this is  done - see above edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you should use positioning for the `div` `index-right-content`. Also, the width is more than it should be... I think I see `640px` for the width, which I think is unnecessary, provided that the widths of the columns inside this `div` is defined.

Comment: the width is just stubbed in for time being. I created a fiddle (show above) to show what is going on more.

Comment: @timpone - I think I see the problem here... in the class `right`, replacing `position: right` with `float: right` will make it work. Also, I added another class named `center` and floated it to the `left`. Here's the code - http://jsfiddle.net/trestles/U7mYT/

Comment: But I must say, everything seems fine. Maybe the main problem was due to the use of `position`. Replace `position` with `float` and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7mYT/4/) adding float to both inner columns in container.