# css variable length columns extending too far - clear:float issue?

Tags: html, css

Not a front-end UI but have a (probably) very easy problem to fix and updated this question [css variable length columns extending too far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585256/css-variable-length-columns-extending-too-far). I have two floated elements shown in this screen shot and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trestles/U7mYT/ . One is floated left and the other (index-right-content) is floated right. The floated right div has two columns of content. The second column is much longer but doesn't expand out the box to push down the container. The index-right-content is posistion:relative.

I can see that if I extend the middle column, it expands out the index-right-content but the right handed column doesn't do that.

thx

Comment: You know that both of your links go to the same page, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use absolute positioning for the second column, which takes it out of the flow - it won't affect the height of the parent div any more.

Better option would be to float both colums in the right block, and add a clear element:

http://jsfiddle.net/U7mYT/3/

```
<div id='content'>
  <div id='featured-lists'>
    <div class='index-left-list'>
      <div class='index-box'>
        <div class="cluster-box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='index-right-content'>
      <div class='index-box'></div>
      <div class='index-box right'>
        <div class="cluster-box"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div> <!-- added -->
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;height:1px;overflow:none;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id='footer'> here is footer </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the last column:

```
.index-box {
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
}

.right {
    float:left;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: ok - this looks like it works. thx so much! is this multiple floating the best way to handle this?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. I never use abs/rel positioning for layouts, I only use it when I need elements to be on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
.right {
```

display: inline; height: yourvalue;
}

and remove the position.

This should work;

Comment: the height will be unknown though, should extend if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using absolute positioning you should float all your columns. You could tidy up the HTML slightly as well:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        Left column
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right column
        <div class="left">
            With two columns
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            In it
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of using un-needed HTML elements for clearing floats you can use a simple clearfix like overflow: hidden; on the container instead:

```
div.wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}

    div.wrap div.left {
        width: 480px;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
    }

    div.wrap div.right {
        width: 480px;
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
    }

        div.wrap div.left div.left, 
        div.wrap div.right div.left, 
        div.wrap div.left div.right, 
        div.wrap div.right div.right {
            width: 240px;
        }
```

I would definitely try to name my classes something a little less design related as well (like primary and secondary rather than left and right).